# Where to put class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm reading Ruby on Rails Guides and found a problem because there is no clearly stated where to put arbitrary class that is not one from MVC.

Concretely, I am reading [Callback classes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callback-classes) and don't know where to put PictureFileCallbacks class.

Can someone help me, since I am relatively new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way by 37signals is documented here : http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns

There is a gist here for explanation
https://gist.github.com/dhh/1014971

You can also do it without using ActiveSupport::Concern by using :

In application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/concerns )
```

And just put module/class in app/concerns.

Do not forget the link between file/directory name and module/class name.